# Как определить последний символ строки?

Tags: c, строки

Так вот, проблема заключается в тот что нужно определить последний символ строки (который является "<"), если таков имеется триггернуть остальную часть кода, если нет выдать ошибку. То есть если в конце строки имеется символ < он должен запускать остальную часть кода. Я новичок без понятия как это делается.. Очень глупый вопрос но таково задание..(

Comment: какой язык?????

Comment: а вы в каком языке программирования новичок или вам общий алгоритм нужен?

Comment: @Danis, да вроде по-русски написал :)))

Comment: если это python то так `string[-1] == "<"`

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл сказать главное ЯЗЫК СИ

Comment: Читайте про [strlen](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ниже привожу код, как можно определить последний символ внутри if, используя [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/), как [предлагал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1223062/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8#comment2140621_1223062) @avp.

В коде ниже я предполагаю что указатель `s` на строку (который должен быть типа `char *`) уже как то заполнен, как угодно, я для примера его заполнил фиксированной строкой, как `char s[100] = "abc<";`.

Дополнительная проверка `s[0] &&` обязательная т.к. если строка пустая (0 символов) то `s[strlen(s) - 1]` выйдет за границы массива, а точнее даже прыгнет далеко в несуществующую память и будет крэш программы. Если у вас указатель на строку может быть ещё нулевой иногда то проверку нужно сделать даже такой `s && s[0] &&`.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##fY1BDoIwEEX3nGJSE2gXGFhbPIE3QBe1FJikDIapC2M8ey0YE1f@5fsv/9vSekNDjDsk6@@dA81hQRr24zH7ZR3OK8qQAkwGSSp4ZpBiR7MAt3VVXaABYa5Wi8PWYA@S24TzPAlp1juSrKCEOqkNFLpQm7jmlk5DL8XJcAB@TIAM@kxCfbacZ/fXpTl8/VeMbw)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char s[100] = "abc<";
    if (s[0] && s[strlen(s) - 1] == '<')
        printf("Last sym is <\n");
    else
        printf("Last sym is not <\n");
}
```